# How to create aliases for the keybindings of ESS-R

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I'm using [ESS](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/ess/README.html) to evaluate R codes inside [spacemacs](https://spacemacs.org/). It has some keybindings to evaluate a line, file, buffer, etc. but the keybindings usually contain 4 key strokes. This is too much. I want to create alises. For instance, map ``  ess-eval-line`   to  so that I can easily evaluate lines.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create alises. For instance, map `` ess-eval-line` to so that I can easily evaluate lines.

Actually, you could create your own key binding for specific functions you want.

Emacs uses `keymaps` to record which keys call which commands, the `global-set-key` function binds, or rebinds, the global `keymap`. Or you could  create keybinding for specific mode with `define-key` like this:

```lisp
;; You bind `ess-eval-line` function to keystroke `Ctrl-C` `Ctrl-e` globally
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-e") 'ess-eval-line)

;; You bind `ess-eval-line` function to keystroke `Ctrl-C` `Ctrl-e` for ess-r-mode
(define-key ess-r-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-e") 'python-switch-to-python)
```

- GNU Documentation: [Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Keymaps.html)
- [Mastering Key Bindings in Emacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs)

Comment: where should I put those LSP codes exactly?

Comment: I am not using `spacemacs`, according to the spacemacs documentation, you should put it into `.spacemacs` file. If you are using `evil`, it seems you need additional configuration, check this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35283/in-spacemacs-how-to-customize-keybindings-that-are-condition-on-language-file